# Memory Error Zipfile for openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-2.7, error-handling, openpyxl

I get this error when I run my Excel import file:

```
File "C:\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\zipfile.py", line 684, in read1
max(n - len_readbuffer, self.MIN_READ_SIZE)
MemoryError
```

I have tried many variations, but I get the same error every time. I spelled everything correctly.

This is my Code

```css
import openpyxl

#Conncetion to Excel Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\XXX\Desktop\Beisspieldatensatz.xlsx')

#Open a specific Workbook sheet
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Methodentest')

tuple(ws1['A1':'C3'])

for rowOfCellObjects in ws1['A1':'C3']:
       for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
               print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
       print('--- END OF ROW ---')
```

I only want to load my three columns in a variable and use this information for some calulations.

Thx in Advance

Comment: Sounds like there may be a problem with the file. All .xlsx files are zipfiles. I'd suggest you try and validate it.

Comment: When i try to read the file on my private pc (Mac with VM with Windows 8), the code run fine. I create a sample with one sheet with a bit content without multipe columns and the code work, but when i want to read more colum then one the same error occurs, is something wrong with the tulpe i got this example from here [link]https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/